# Calculating torus cap volume

Tags: geometry, volume

Is there any formula for calculating volume of torus "cap" (I'm not sure if I'm calling it right)? I mean something like this

[image]

I know two torus radiuses and cap height.
It would be helpful to measure fluid volume resting inside part of pipe shaped like torus (in my embedded project)